# Create a method to get integers from a https web page and store it in a array

Tags: java, arrays, methods, https, html

Can someone please help me create a method to get the integers (listed below) from [this link](https://www.norsk-tipping.no/gar/wco?event=getResultInfo&game_id=13&DrawID=1260&target=1&bet=10&keno_level=10) and store them in an array using Java? I'm new to Java and I've searched around and I can't any info or working examples of how to do it.

The integers are:

```
17,04,2011,1,2,7,10,13,23,24,25,26,27,38,39,41,43,45,48,49,55,59,62
```

All integers will change each time the method is called.

Comment: Please show us the code that you have written so far, or be more specific about the part of this problem you are having difficulty with.  If you are completely lost, your best bet is to start by reading the Oracle Java Tutorials ... or a good text book.

Comment: I have read the tutorials on [Working with URLs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/index.html) over at Oracle.com and non of the examples are working for me except [Parsing a URL](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/urlInfo.html). What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You need to do this:

- retrieve the web page. Use URL and URLConnection for this.
- Parse the HTML. It looks like this is an XHTML page, so you could use any XML API for this. As an alternative, for this simple structure something like a regular expression that throws away anything which is in `<...>` could work, too.
- put the numbers from the HTML into a new array. You might want to count them first, to know the right size, or put them in while you are parsing, and later cut off the array. (Or they are always the same number.)

Comment: How would I go about doing this?